# VB.NET to create and run batch file issues

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, visual-studio-2012, batch-processing

Here is the code i am running, and currently having issues with.

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
    Dim path As String
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim sb1 As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim Project As String = txtProject.Text
    Dim Building As String = txtBuilding.Text

    'Get the building and project number from some form of user input. They're predefined here:
    Building = "A1"
    Project = "10"

    If (folderDlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        path = folderDlg.SelectedPath
        Dim root As Environment.SpecialFolder = folderDlg.RootFolder
    Else
        Return
    End If

    Me.Visible = False

    sb.AppendLine("")
    sb.AppendLine("_.``")
    sb.AppendLine(Building)
    sb.AppendLine(Project)
    sb.AppendLine("ZOOM")
    sb.AppendLine("e")
    sb.AppendLine("_.qsave")
    sb.AppendLine("_.quit")

    IO.File.WriteAllText(path & "\TB Edit.scr", sb.ToString())

    sb1.AppendLine("FOR %%D IN (*.DWG) DO " & Chr(34) & "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Acade 2013\acad.exe" & Chr(34) & " %%D /B " & Chr(34) & path & "\TB Edit.scr" & Chr(34))
    sb1.AppendLine("Pause")
    sb1.AppendLine("END")

    IO.File.WriteAllText(path & "\TB Edit.bat", sb1.ToString())

    Process.Start(path & "\TB Edit.bat")

    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(path & "\TB Edit.bat")
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(path & "\TB Edit.scr")
```

When the batch file runs, this is what i get...
'Added the pause to see what's going on-

```
C:\Users\Owner\Dropbox\CADMASTER TECH  - SOUTH VALLEY\THOMAS\VB Programs\Title B
lock Edit\Title Block Edit\bin\Release>FOR %D IN (*.DWG) DO "C:\Program Files\Au
todesk\Acade 2013\acad.exe" %D /B "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\TB Edit.scr"

C:\Users\Owner\Dropbox\CADMASTER TECH  - SOUTH VALLEY\THOMAS\VB Programs\Title B
lock Edit\Title Block Edit\bin\Release>Pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

But when i don't delete the batch file at the end of the program, and go to it's location and run it, it runs just fine, like it should!

Been messing with this for about two days now... Any ideas?

Comment: Incidentally, `Dim root As Environment.SpecialFolder = folderDlg.RootFolder` should be `Dim root As String = folderDlg.RootFolder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and go to it's location

there's your clue! have a good look at the output you posted.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Added this to make it work ->     `sb1.AppendLine("cd " path)`. Epic brain fart...